# On iOS, how to disable popup that reminds new versions and updates in old versions from Crashlytics Beta

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

This is regarding the iOS Enterprise apps downloaded from Crashlytics Beta Platform.

Whenever there're new versions uploaded, when the old apps are launched, there will be popup that reminds user of new versions and updates in Crashlytics Beta. This seems to be automatically added by Crashlytics Beta.

Just want to ask, is it possible to disable the popup so that testers can keep using the old app to do regression test? We couldn't seem to be able to find any configurations or settings about this.

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here. There is not a way to disable that notification currently on a per version basis. If you've explicitly installed an older version of the app through the Beta app then the new version popup won't be triggered. But if you're on an older version of the app through the normal install flow, then the update prompt will show up.

Comment: If you're seeing that behavior in a reproducible manner, I'd recommend filing a bug with support(at)fabric(dot)io.