# Fabric Beta iOS Update Notification does not appear

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

We integrated crashlytics in on of our apps and are using fabric beta to distribute the app to testers.
On iOS I remember that there was in the past an alert on startup if somebody installed an old version of an app. Currently this alert does not appear anymore.

Is this feature still available? I couldn't see any documentation about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here and yes the functionality still exists. The check for a new version of your app happens every two hours. If you update and install a new version of the app before the check completes, then there won't be an update notification. Also, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49285176/3975963) if you've explicitly installed an older version of the app from the Beta app that shows older versions, we won't prompt for an update. The most common cause of this though is updating your app and then installing it right away as you know the build finished.

Comment: Hi Mike, do we still need to open the app to show the alert for the update. Thanks

Comment: No, on Android, it will show up within the Notifications display on it's own.

Comment: Hi Mike, I haven't seen the Fabric Beta iOS Update Notification in our app for quite some time. I haven't installed explicitly an older version. Are there other things to consider?